# Mail Function configuration - web SMS

Tags: php, html, sms-gateway

I am using the code below for sending web mails and SMS notifications when users choose “A” value from the "servicerequired" drop-down menu. It works perfectly fine but I'd to change the time schedule from “Disabled” everyday from 8PM to 5AM to :

**Mon to Fri** “Disabled" between 8PM to 5AM and between 7AM to 4PM
**Sun and Saturday** “Disabled” between 8PM to 5AM

Here is my current code which stops web SMS from sending everyday from 8PM to 5AM:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
           $sms="";
           $subject="";
           $from = "";
           $service = $_REQUEST['servicerequired'] ;
           $headers = "";
           $message="message";
if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A' && (date("G")>5 && date("G")<20)  ){ 
           @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

The HTML Markup:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="servicerequired">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<input value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This has doing my head in for a couple of days now. I have done some research and came up with this solution but I am not sure if it is the best practice or even works.

My Solution:

```
if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A')
{
    if(date("W")=0 || date("W")=6) && (date("G")>5 && date("G")<20)
    {
        @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
    }
    else if
    {
        (date("W")>0 && date("W")<6) && (date("G")>5 && date("G")<20)
    }
    else
    {
        @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header);
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help and Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**********

Try :

```
if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A')
{
switch (date("N"))
{
 case 6:  //Saturday
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20)
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
 break;
 case 7:  //Sunday
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20) 
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
 break;
 case 1:  //Monday
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20 && date("G")>16 && date("G")<7)
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
 break;
 case 2:  //Tuesday
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20 && date("G")>16 && date("G")<7)
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
 break;
 case 3:  //Wednesday 
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20 && date("G")>16 && date("G")<7)
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
 break;
 case 4:  //Thursday
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20 && date("G")>16 && date("G")<7)
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
 break;
 case 5:  //Friday
 if(date("G")>5 && date("G")<20 && date("G")>16 && date("G")<7)
 {
    @mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
}
}
```

Comment: @AhmenAli Thanks. let me try it. I'll get back to you shortly :)

Comment: I don't recieve any mails when I use your code. what if I remove this condition if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A') and try only Friday code?

Comment: there is a missing '}' at the end of the code,had you added it?

Comment: yes I did it before the test but still there is no notification. how can I remove the if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A') condition and only test Friday part to see if it works or not?

Comment: My bad,i forgot  to add `break;` after each case,so that the loop would stop,no need for more testing,i updated the answer,i believe it will work perfectly now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33347/discussion-between-mohammad-moezzi-and-ahmed-ali)